# How do you repeat a test in PHPUnit?

Tags: php, phpunit

I know about the "--repeat" option, but I'd rather define the repeating within the test and per test. In my unit tests there are tests I don't want to repeat, and there are tests I want to repeat more than others.

I was thinking:

```
protected function tearDown() {
  if (test has not been ran 3 times) {
      $this->runTest(); // Re-run the test
  }
}
```

This doesn't seem to work, nor does $this->run(). I've looked at the PHPUnit source code but I'm not sure. I'm guessing it's checking the test status and if it's been ran it denies running it again.

Comment: why would you need that in a unit-test? Oo

Comment: It's for an abstract class that extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase. The purpose is to define X repeats per test instead of global X repeats denoted by --repeat.

Comment: I'd also like to find a solution for this. @Gordon - my case is that I'm testing a service over socket connection (thrift:php). It may happen that tests fail only because of network overload, which in fact doesn't mean . In case of Timeout exception I'd like to rerun the test, so that it passes or any other error/exception is thrown.

Comment: @tkoomzaaskz cant you just mock the remote end? or increase the timeout?

Comment: @Gordon I cannot increase the timeout, since I'd need to modify settings of the external service, which I don't want to do. Could you explain what do you mean by mocking the remote end? If you meant that I shall use a mock object instead of a real service, this won't do, because we're testing the service and service-php communication. So the service has to be a real instance.

Comment: @tkoomzaaskz yes, that's what I meant and what is suggested in the PHPUnit Manual, too: "When your application interacts with a web service you want to test it without actually interacting with the web service.". It's not a unit-test when you are testing against the real service.

Comment: @Gordon: what solution would you recommend then (when I want to provide advanced tests for a real webservice)?

Comment: @tkoomzaaskz You could use Selenium to do an End-To-End Test, but in general I'd recommend not to test it at all.

Answer (score 17):

PHPUnit has a repeat option within the command line runner. This works as follows for a test that repeats 3 times:

```bash
phpunit --repeat 3 myTest.php
```

Comment: I think this is only valid before version 10

Comment: @MarshallDavis Yes, it has been removed from the version 10. Here's a quick around: https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/issues/5174#issuecomment-1510002606

Answer (score 6):

This is a bit of a roundabout way of doing this but it's the cleanest I could come up with:

```
/**
 * @dataProvider numberOfTests
 */
public function test()
{
    // Do your test
}

public function numberOfTests() 
{
    for ($i = 0; $i < 100; $i++) {
       yield [];
    }
}
```

The benefit of this is setUp and tearDown methods will be run for each invocation of the loop.

Comment: This is a good solution as setup teardown methods are run for each invocation of the testcase

Answer (score 2):

There's far more to running a test than `setUp`, `run`, and `tearDown`. For one thing, each test method is run against a new instance of the test case. Don't forget about `@dataProvider` and the other annotations, code coverage, etc. You really don't want to do this.

For the few cases you *absolutely* need it, code the loop in the test method itself.

Answer (score 1):

As @reusen mentioned, we had the command

```bash
phpunit --repeat 3 myTest.php
```

But this feature has been [removed and not planned to be re-implemented](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/issues/5174). At least, not at the moment.

Currently there's this [workaround](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/issues/5174#issuecomment-1510002606)

```bash
while php vendor/bin/phpunit tests/ExampleTest.php --stop-on-failure; do echo; done
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to take a step back and create a test that runs your tests!

You need a loop that goes something along the lines of:

```
$myTest = \my\test\class();
foreach($iterations){
    $myTest->setup();
    $myTest->doTestyStuff();
    $myTest->tearDown();
}
```

the code you posted won't work because each test needs the setup and teardown to be run *each time the test runs*.

Comment: I had it in tearDown because of the fact tearDown is ran after each test. That's how I was thinking of creating a loop. I would break the loop by checking a static iterator or something.

What you're suggesting above I think I can work from, but I'm trying to run each test X number of times and not every test needs to be ran more than once or the same number of times.

Answer (score 0):

If you use terminal fish, you can run

```bash
for i in seq(seq 10)                                                                                                                                          
    sail artisan test --filter MyControllerTest
end
```

Answer (score -1):

Can this not be achieved with a do-while loop?

```
protected function tearDown() {
    $i = 0;
    do {
        $this->runTest(); // Re-run the test
        $i++;
    } while($i < 3);
}
```

Comment: The repeating isn't my problem, I can figure that out easily enough. It's that calling $test->runTest() does nothing. Also since tearDown is called after every test, your code assuming $test->runTest() worked would put it in an indefinite loop.